Resource leak when using ExoPlayer with SimpleCache
Since I started to use SimpleCache with ExoPlayer I keep getting LeakedCloseableViolation, as soon as I start playing a new file even though I'm calling the cache release method.
Here's how I'm initializing the player
...
this.simpleCache = new SimpleCache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "streamCaching"), new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(25 * 1024 * 1024), new StandaloneDatabaseProvider(context));
factory = new CacheDataSource.Factory().setCache(this.simpleCache).setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(httpDataSourceFactory);    
...

Then here's my release code that is called as soon as the player is stopped
this.player.release();
  if (this.simpleCache != null) {
          this.simpleCache.release();
          this.simpleCache = null;
  }

Any idea why I keep getting this
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.LeakedClosableViolation: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidCloseGuardReporter.report(StrictMode.java:1987)
    at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.warnIfOpen(CloseGuard.java:345)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dispose(SQLiteDatabase.java:427)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:408)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:291)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:278)
    at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
    at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.openWithCallSite(CloseGuard.java:295)
    at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:263)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1415)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1355)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:996)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:470)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:437)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.CachedContentIndex$DatabaseStorage.exists(CachedContentIndex.java:799)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.CachedContentIndex.initialize(CachedContentIndex.java:201)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.SimpleCache.initialize(SimpleCache.java:582)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.SimpleCache.access$000(SimpleCache.java:49)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.SimpleCache$1.run(SimpleCache.java:268)



The problem it is possible to has something to do with how the cache is accessed or used in the code or with ExoPlayer library itself and the library itself the problem may be. Try to release the cache when you are through with it, rather than using it after releasing the same. Don't attempt to use the cache from multiple threads concurrently. Furthermore, provide that the cache directory which you are operating (context.getCacheDir()) must be readable and writable by your application.
